# google autocomplete setComponentRestrictions

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, reactjs

Is there any restriction on setting the `setComponentRestrictions` value ? Because it is not working while setting dynamic values.

#### Scenario 1 (Works fine)

In this scenario I hard coded the county value to search only specific cities in that country.So this works fine when I use hard coded value.

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchCity');
var options = { types: ['(cities)'],componentRestrictions: {country: 'us' }};
var autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(cityInput,options);`
```

#### Scenario 2 (Not working)

In this, I have another text field which I am using to find country using autcomplete and storing the short_code value in shortNameCountry Id.But this is not working when I am passing dynamic value.

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchCity');
var countryOpt = $("#shortNameCountry").val().toLowerCase();
var options = {types: ['(cities)'], componentRestrictions: {country: countryOpt }};
var autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
```

(I have added my scenarios. But I dont know stackoverflow keep on ask me to add more details. I am just writting this lines to solve that alert.)
Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your code uses the  property `componentRestrictions`, which will have the value of the input when you create the autocomplete.

To change this property you must call the method `setComponentRestrictions` when the value of the input changes.

```js
function initialize() {

        var iso           = ['AD','AE','AF','AG','AI','AL','AM','AO','AQ','AR','AS','AT','AU','AW','AX','AZ','BA','BB','BD','BE','BF','BG','BH','BI','BJ','BL','BM','BN','BO','BQ','BR','BS','BT','BV','BW','BY','BZ','CA','CC','CD','CF','CG','CH','CI','CK','CL','CM','CN','CO','CR','CU','CV','CW','CX','CY','CZ','DE','DJ','DK','DM','DO','DZ','EC','EE','EG','EH','ER','ES','ET','FI','FJ','FK','FM','FO','FR','GA','GB','GD','GE','GF','GG','GH','GI','GL','GM','GN','GP','GQ','GR','GS','GT','GU','GW','GY','HK','HM','HN','HR','HT','HU','ID','IE','IL','IM','IN','IO','IQ','IR','IS','IT','JE','JM','JO','JP','KE','KG','KH','KI','KM','KN','KP','KR','KW','KY','KZ','LA','LB','LC','LI','LK','LR','LS','LT','LU','LV','LY','MA','MC','MD','ME','MF','MG','MH','MK','ML','MM','MN','MO','MP','MQ','MR','MS','MT','MU','MV','MW','MX','MY','MZ','NA','NC','NE','NF','NG','NI','NL','NO','NP','NR','NU','NZ','OM','PA','PE','PF','PG','PH','PK','PL','PM','PN','PR','PS','PT','PW','PY','QA','RE','RO','RS','RU','RW','SA','SB','SC','SD','SE','SG','SH','SI','SJ','SK','SL','SM','SN','SO','SR','SS','ST','SV','SX','SY','SZ','TC','TD','TF','TG','TH','TJ','TK','TL','TM','TN','TO','TR','TT','TV','TW','TZ','UA','UG','UM','US','UY','UZ','VA','VC','VE','VG','VI','VN','VU','WF','WS','YE','YT','ZA','ZM','ZW'];
            goo           =  google.maps,
            input         = document.getElementById('searchCity'),
            country       = document.getElementById('shortNameCountry'),
            options       = {types: ['(cities)']},
            autoComplete  = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
        
        goo.event.addDomListener(country,'input',function(){
          var val=this.value.trim().toUpperCase();
          if(iso.indexOf(val)>-1){
            this.style.background='white';
            input.value=' ';
            autoComplete
            .setComponentRestrictions({country:val});
            
          }
          else{
            this.style.background='red';
          }
        });
        goo.event.trigger(country,'input');
        
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<input id="searchCity"/>
  <input id="shortNameCountry" size="2" maxlength="2" value="de"/>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But this is not fit with my requirement. Let me explain clearly. I have two autocomplete text field one is for country and one is for city. Since there is options to to find only country I am storing the country short_code in hidden filed(shortNameCountry). So when the user search the city filed it should get the value from hidden field as country options and find the cities.